# Python - Best way to count the amount of times a dictionary value in a list of dictionaries appeared?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"Audiofile": "test1.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:47:22.478868", "Author": "Lisa"}, {"Audiofile": "test2.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:47:32.239118", "Author": "Mike"},
{"Audiofile": "test2.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:49:15.535216", "Author": "John"}]
```

In the end, i want to have a list of dictionaries like this, in this example:

```
[{"test1.mp3": 1}, {"test2.mp3": 2}]
```

where it lists all Audiofiles and  the amount of times they occured in this list.

What would be best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

res = Counter(x['Audiofile'] for x in d)
print(dict(res))
```

**Output:**

```
{'test1.mp3': 1, 'test2.mp3': 2}
```

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
res = [{k: len(list(g))} for k, g in groupby(d, lambda x: x['Audiofile'])]
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` is not limited to `list`s, you might do `Counter(x['Audiofile'] for x in d)` in place of `Counter([x['Audiofile'] for x in d])`

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over the dictionaries and do it, instead of having a list of dictionaries, you could generate one dictionary to act as the counter.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(int)
for audio_data in data_dictionaries: #your list of dictionaries
    counter[audio_data['Audiofile']] += 1
```

If you have to get it as a list of dictionaries then you could just convert this counter using simple list comprehension like so:

```py
list_dictionaries = [{k:v} for k,v in counter.items()]
```

I hope this solves what you are looking for - this does everything in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

arr = [{"Audiofile": "test1.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:47:22.478868", "Author": "Lisa"},
       {"Audiofile": "test2.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:47:32.239118", "Author": "Mike"},
       {"Audiofile": "test2.mp3", "Time": "2020-09-03 13:49:15.535216", "Author": "John"}]
cnt = Counter()
for item in arr:
    cnt[item['Audiofile']] += 1
print(dict(cnt))
```